# disabled attribute not working in symfony on radio button

Tags: symfony

Here is my attribute

```
        ->add(
            'target',
            DaimChoiceType::class,
            [
                'required' => true,
                'disabled' => $this->disabledStatus(),
                'label' => 'attr.target',
                'choices' => [
                    'common_settings.ui.yes' => 1,
                    'common_settings.ui.no' => 0,
                ],
                'label_attr' => ['class' => 'radio-inline health-target-radio'],
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => false,
            ]
        )
```

Here is my code

```
    {% if viewMode is defined %}
        {% set disabled = {'attr':{'disabled': 'disabled'}} %}
    {% endif %}

{{ form_row(form.healthInsuranceType.target, disabled) }} // disabled attribute not working here

{{ form_row(form.healthInsuranceType.issueDate, disabled) }} //disabled attribute working here
```

Please help me to fix the issue in symfony

Comment: What is `DaimChoiceType`?

Comment: it works for my form codes. what are error messages and custom form type codes ?

Comment: thank you for your quick replay DaimChoiceType is ChoiceType::class. i want to disable all fields on that form. but radio buttons are still active and others types are  disabled(i can do it with javascript. but this way is not working in my form). Let me know if you have any solution.